# I have two classes(A and B), and I'm trying to use a method from A in B. The method in A, simply finds the index of an item in a list:

Tags: python-3.x, inheritance, multiple-inheritance

I have three classes(A, I and B), where A is inheriting from I. I'm trying to use a method ,from A, in B. The method in A, simply finds the index of an item in a list. I have:

File 1:

```
class I:
  def__init__(self,s):
     self.s = s

class A(I):

  def __init__(self,n):
    self.n = n
    self.lst = []
    for i in range(n):
      self.lst.append([])
  .....

  def get_item_location(self, item):
    for index in range(len(self.lst)):
        if item in self.lst[index]:
            return index
```

File 2:

```
from A import classA
class B:
  def __init__(self,n):
     self._model = A(n)

  def something(self, dest_point):
     print (self._model.get_item_location(self._item))
```

Where the type of self._item is Class I, now this prints None for me, where I expect it to return the index number of the list which the item is inside it, and the item is inside the list. When I used get_item_location function, it gives me an integer, but when Class B is using it, it returns None. I beleive it's something to do with that self._item, but I have not come up with any solution yet. I'd really appreciate it if someone could help.

Comment: Please make a [mcve]. There's so much missing from your code that there's no possible way we can guess what's going on. What is `self._model` in class B? How is it created? Assuming its an `A` instance, where do its inner lists get populated. How is `self._item` assigned? How are you testing the code, so that you think class `A` works on its own?

Comment: I edited the code for self._model. Class A does not work on its own, and Class B takes these methods from A and uses it. I'm trying my best to simplify the question, but it seems not possible!

Comment: the inner lists in lst, get populated by an add method in Class A, which B uses that method to implement items inside the lists. Basically get_item_location, should return the index of the list that the item is in it. So lets say: lst = [[item,a,b,c],[a],[b],[]], then get_item_location(item) should return 0.

Comment: Presumably the object you're saving as `self._item` isn't getting put in an inner list, so there is no index where it can be found. We have no possible way to tell why, since the code that saves an item and the code that populates the list is not included in your question. (The classes you show are also giving syntax errors due to capitalizing `Class`, but even with that fixed they don't do anything useful to demonstrate your issue.)